# Jumbo mode with android dx compiler on mac os x

Tags: android, dx

i'm trying to use jumbo mode for android dx on mac osx in a large project (with Eclipse+ADT) using the flag "dex.force.jumbo=true" inside project.properties file.
It works on Windows but not on various macs where I tried. 
Here's the error:

```
[2014-05-07 16:04:41 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2014-05-07 16:04:41 - ****MyApp*****] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Has anyone had the same problem on mac?

Comment: Do you know your version of dex is late enough to support that?  I'd be tempted to grep the dex binary for 'jumbo' and see if it is found or not, ie if the option parsing code even knows about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried with sdk build-tools from 17 to the last one released.

Comment: AFAIK, jumbo mode is only for strings. It does not affect the 65535 method limit.